# How do i combine two arrays php parallel and result in Json

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have two array with comma in Mysql database.

`data[]= xyz,abc,raw;`

`value[] = 20,30,50;`

I want this Json result=>

`[["xyz",20],  ["abc",30],["raw",50],]`

Help me, Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? or are you expecting us do your job for you?

Comment: `$slice=explode(",", $user_data['Slice']);                             $val =explode(",", $user_data['Slice_percentage']);                  $c = array_combine($slice, $val);
echo json_encode ($c);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [array_combine()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) then [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: My data has been populated but still I have not solved my problem. I new to Json so I didn't have Idea about it. Please help me : I am Getting {"xyz":50,"xxx":20,"ffff":30}. But I need [["xyz",20], ["abc",30],["raw",50],]. What is the difference,an dhow I get Populated with this format

Comment: @mark: looks like OP simply wants to combine parallel records into single records, e.g. `array('xyz', 20)`, not `array('xyz' => 20)`.